# How to get URL from Crawled instead of Scraped from in Portia spider deployment?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd, urlparse, portia

I am deploying a Portia spider in scrapyd.
While deploying I am passing URLs for every link parsing

Example: 
The URL(say URL_1) crawled by the spider is `http://www.example.com/query1` and the URL(say URL_2) I am passing is `http://www.example.com/query2` to extract content.

My spider extracted the content from URL_2 and stored it into respective items. This is fine.

I am having the [URL] item and URL_2 stored in the item, but what I want is URL_1 to be stored in the [URL] item.

Any Solution?